# PyCharm Directly Open Python File

Tags: python, ide, pycharm

I switched to PyCharm a couple of months ago, but I can't figure out how to get rid of the welcome screen when I open files.

More specifically, I've set up my mac to open all .py files using PyCharm. However, when I double click on a .py file, it's the Welcome screen that opens up and not the .py file.

How do I get PyCharm to just open the python script in the editor, without showing me a welcome screen?

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm displays the Welcome screen when no project is open. From this screen, you can quickly access the major starting points of PyCharm. The Welcome screen appears when you close the current project in the only instance of PyCharm. If you are working with multiple projects, usually closing a project results in closing the PyCharm window in which it was running, except for the last project, closing this will show the Welcome screen.